# How to prevent WebView auto refresh when screen rotation

Tags: android, android-webview

My application - Activity with WebView was auto refresh when screen rotation and my activity back to the first 1.

Example: WebView handle 3 activity(A, B, C) when I switching from A->B or B-C then it will back to A when screen is rotating.

My question: how can we keep activity alive event screen rotation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Highlighting @kirgy comment, You have to add  `orientation|screenSize` to your manifest if your API > 3.2 , It wont work without it in some cases.

Comment: Nope, nope, nope.  Please allow your configuration to update when it should.

Comment: @NightlyNexus what can be the implications of doing this within a webview?

Comment: @cgomezmendez Always allow your Views to restore their state.  Yes, in this case, a WebView does not have state to save and restore, but is the WebView the only part of the instance state of your Activity?  Almost certainly not.

Answer (score 49):

There is more than one approach to tackle this problem.

The easy way out is to add [`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) to the relevant `Activity` in your manifest. By setting this flag you tell Android to not destroy the `Activity` and that you're going to handle all orientation changes (if any) yourself.

The more modern approach would be to put the `WebView` inside a `Fragment` and make it retain its instance, using the `setRetainInstance(true)` flag. The hosting `Activity` will still get destroyed on orientation changes, but the `Fragment` containing the `WebView` will simply be detached and re-attached, without the need to re-create itself. You can find [an example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentRetainInstance.html) of this feature in the API demos. Keep in mind that the support library offers a pre-Honeycomb compatible implementation of fragments, so don't be fooled by the API level of the 'regular'  `Fragment` class.

Comment: Your first "easiest" way to do this is the only way. The "more modern approach" won't work in this case (well, it'll work, but it'll leak memory) because a WebView is tied to an Activity's Context upon instantiation. Check out [Dianne Hackborn's comments on that](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/cWnxkQ8RLeY/RA1n77EDeR8J).

Comment: @mkuech: The latter is the case for any view, not just `WebView`s - that's why you'll always find yourself re-inflating views on a fragment level in `onCreateView()` or `onActivityCreated()`. I didn't go into specifics in my answer above, but with `setRetainInstance(true)` you could make the 'old' `WebView` save its state to a bundle and restore it afterwards. It does mean the `WebView` will have to rebuild its content (read: reload the url), so it's visually not as fast/smooth as handling the `Activity`'s configuration changes manually.

Comment: But you don't need to use a `Fragment` to save a `WebView`'s state. You can just use the standard state management methods from the `Activity` or `Fragment` if that's all you need. `setRetainInstance(true)` isn't _normally_ needed for this simple use case. It more just replaces `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance`, and is useful for things like keeping a `Thread` active across configuration changes. I'd avoid complicating things. Besides, since merely saving a `WebView`'s state won't keep it from redrawing/reloading, the first solution is the only real way to keep it seamless when rotating.

Comment: You rock. This is the best solution so far.

Comment: @mkuench You make a very important point and provide an excellent source. You deserve more upvotes than you got. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me, the webview keeps reloading.

Answer (score 6):

Add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your manifest file to prevent restarts when the screen orientation changes.

like::

```
   <activity android:name=".MyActivity"     
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange) for some references.

Comment: Dear Abhina8, thank you so much..it's really greate..I tested it's working very fine for me :).

Comment: A note for Android 3.2+ (API 13) - from this version onwards a screen rotate also causes a screen size change which will refresh the UI. You need to declare "orientation|screenSize" instead of just "orientation". This is all in the above Android article suggested by @MH. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange